# How to get the notmuch message-id and thread-id from a maildir message filename already in the notmuch db?

Tags: maildir, notmuch

Let's assume that I make a notmuch query that returns files:

```
$ notmuch search --output=files tag:inbox from:love
```

This returns a list of files, pointing to Maildir messages. Now I pick one of these files (already in the notmuch database), for instance with

```
FILENAME=$(notmuch search --output=files tag:inbox from:love | fzf)
```

and I would like to get its message-id and thread-id in the notmuch database. **From the variable $FILENAME, I would like to find the message-id in notmuch.**

A very sloppy way to do this is to parse the file, read the headers from/subject/date and make a notmuch query `notmuch search from:{...} subject:{...} date:{..}`. But since the filenames are already stored in the database, I guess there should be a canonical and robust way to obtain the mesage-id from the filename.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a way through the notmuch python bindings, see https://notmuch.readthedocs.io/projects/notmuch-python/en/latest/database.html?highlight=filename#notmuch.Database.find_message_by_filename

A working bash one liner is

```
threadId=$(python3 -c "import notmuch; db = notmuch.Database(); print(db.find_message_by_filename('$FILENAME').get_thread_id())");
```

and the unpacked python3 code is

```
import notmuch
db = notmuch.Database()
msg = db.find_message_by_filename('filename of the maildir message')
msg.get_thread_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way of searching notmuch database based on maildir filename in [NOTMUCH-SEARCH-TERMS(7)](https://notmuchmail.org/manpages/notmuch-search-terms-7/)

You can get Message-Id and notmuch thread id directly from Your search by iterating on Message-Ids:

```bash
for message_id in $(notmuch search --output=messages 'tag:inbox from:love')
do
  thread_id=$(notmuch search --output=threads $message_id)
  echo "$thread_id - $message_id"
done
```

Or you can iterate on threads and get associated Message-Ids:

```bash
for thread_id in $(notmuch search --output=threads 'tag:inbox from:love')
do
  # sed is here only to provide the output in the same format as in the first example
  notmuch search --output=messages $thread_id | sed "s/^/$thread_id - /"
done
```

Whatever suits your needs better. Both for loops prints result in following format:

```
thread:THREAD_ID - id:MESSAGE_ID
…
```

If you want to get *From*, *Date*, *Subject* headers You can also extract it directly from notmuch database using jq without need to parse maildir file using [formail(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/formail) or similar tool.

```bash
notmuch search --format=json id:MESSAGE_ID | jq -r '.[].subject'
```

Comment: I modified the question to make clear that I want to retrieve the message-id from a single $FILENAME. The goal is not to list the message-id and thread-id in the query.

Comment: np. I'm glad you've found the solution on your own.